# Updating to/installing Ubuntu 12.04 from 11.10

Tags: 12.04, live-cd

I would like to upgrade my PC from 11.10 to 12.04.

I tried to upgrade when I kept getting messages that 11.10 unsupported now. My PC crashed and I had to reinstalled 11.10
I made a boot disk for 12.04 (64 bit) and tried running it. 
It appears to be starting OK. and get various messages flashing on screen till

Starting network connection manager  [OK]
starting crash report submission daemon   [OK]

after a while a grey screen opens with a mouse pointer, then it goes blank and hangs.

ctrl-alt-delete shuts it down.

PC has 969mb memory
AMD Sempron processor 3100+
Graphics VESA 6330 (on board)
current OS is 11.10 32 bit (I tried 32 bit 12.04 with similar results)
Disc has 122gb but not relevant for live cd running?

Comment: You can't skip versions in the upgrading process (exception LTS to LTS). You have to completely reinstall 12.04 over your 11.10. **Have a backup before**

Comment: I can't install 12.04 as the cd I have doesn't start up properly to be able to install. The cd will run on a work PC I use. And I thought that 12.04 was next lts version after 10.10 anyway?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

to run an upgrade to the next version.

Comment: I tried to upgrade once and my PC crashed so I thought I would try running the live-cd version before trying again, I don't mind a fresh install but the live cd just hangs after a while and only responds to a shut-down command (see above).